# Reading And Analysing .txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

Im new to matlab and am having some trouble with example.

The Colorado River Drainage Basin covers parts of seven western states. A series of dams has been constructed on the Colorado River and its tributaries to store runoff water and to generate low-cost hydroelectric power. The ability to regulate the flow of water has made the growth of agriculture and population in these arid desert states possible. Even during periods of extended drought, a steady, reliable source of water and electricity has been available to the basing states. Lake Powell is one of these reservoirs lake_powell.txt contains data on the water level in the reservoir for the eight years 2000 to 2007.

a) Use nested for loops to read one water level value at a time into the lake_powell matrix.

```
lake_powell(month,year) = fscanf(fileID, '%f', 1);
```

Print the lake_powell matrix with title and year column headings.

b) Use mean to determine the average elevation of the water level for each year and the overall average for the eight-year period over which the data were collected.

c) Use find and length to determine how many months of each year exceed the overall average for the eight-year period.

d) Create a report that lists the month (number) and the year for each of the months that 
exceed the overall average. For example, June is month 6. Use find.

e) Determine and print the average elevation of the water for each month for the eight-year period. Use mean.

f) Plot the water level values in lake_powell using

```
date=2000:1/12:2008-1/12;
plot(date,lake_powell(:))
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Water level, ft')
```

Comment: Sounds like assignment. What exactly do you have problems with? How did you try to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question?

Comment: What did you tried to do (even if failed?) did you first try to use matlab just for the purpose of taking a mean or length of a vector?

Comment: My main problem is figuring out how to use the nested for loops with fscanf, fopen, and fprintf to read and display the values from the .txt file, which was given.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using textscan instead of fscanf.

testscan reads in a delimited file line by line where each line has a consistent format.

Read the documentation for textscan and you should have your solution.